Testing astrodynamics software
As I’ve been developing my own solutions (and implementing existing ones) to problems in astrodynamics to solve textbook questions and to build applications, I’m becoming increasingly interested in the best practices for testing these things both for correctness and for production deployment (I’m new to the field as a software engineer).
I mostly work with python at the moment and have done a lot of unit testing of functions in scientific computing, but I’d be interested in how real teams test their propagators, analyze their performance, and so on—as well as how you might have done so in your own libraries/work. Any resources, general best practices, or recommended repositories for this?

Just because i am sure, someone will post this as an answer: By accepting the EULA, you agreed not to use STK for validating or testing of your own algorithms

@CallMeTom that's good to know! I haven't had the opportunity to use STK yet but it seems like I'll be learning it soon.

David Vallado's code has test cases for the wide range of astrodynamics applications his great book addresses. https://celestrak.org/software/vallado-sw.php

"solutions to problems in astrodynamics" and "how real teams test their propagators, analyze their performance" in the context of active spacecraft trajectories is probably a little bit beyond the scope of what to ask in Scientific Computing SE but there are a lot of folks who will chime in on questions about ODE solvers so you might consider asking a different but related question there as well.

This is not really on topic here, and in any case is way too broad and seems to be asking for resources. There are entire books about software verification and validation.
